# Можно ли создать 2 функции $(document).ready на одной странице?

Tags: jquery, javascript

У меня есть одна фунцкция $(document).ready, которая подключатся ко всем страницам. А на одной из страниц мне надо создать еще одну собственную такую функцию, для дополнительных действий. Будут ли работать обе эти функции? Если нет, то какой выход?

Comment: Конечно будут.

Comment: Более того, даже если вызвать такой код после загрузки страницы, он тоже корректно отработает. Просто каллбек вызовется сразу же.

Comment: @Helena2977 А [проверить](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/t78n7jwa/) самостоятельно? @lampa кругом прав.

Comment: @Sergiks, ну или хотя бы прочитать двадцать строк описания в документации, что бы найти ответ.

Comment: Проверила, просто не сообразила сразу, как проверить. Что Вы от чайника хотите? :) А 20 строк в документации на английском тоже не так легко прочитать, если ты этого английского не учил никогда, кроме как по документациям разным. :(

Comment: @Helena2977, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

[[@Helena2977](/users/24157/helena2977)](/users/24157/helena2977),

[Русский перевод документации по JQuery](http://jquery-docs.ru/),

[Событие ready()](http://jquery-docs.ru/events/ready/), в описании последние два предложения:

> У Вас может быть сколько угодно событий $(document).ready на странице. В этом случае функции выполняются в том порядке, в котором они были добавлены.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответы и за ссылку.

Answer (score 2):

Будут работать. Также не забывайте, что переменные, определенные в первом `ready` будут недоступны во всех других.